# iPhone open multiple view controllers on table view item click

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, tableview

Is it possible to open different view controllers depending on witch table view cell user clicks? I tried to do that with:

```
[self presentViewController:obj animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but when next view is presented, there is no navigation bar and I can't go back to table view.

**EDIT:**

Here is MasterViewController class that I am using

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSArray *viewArray;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController
@synthesize items,itemImges;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"7" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 480.0);
    }
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    }
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"MasterTitle",@"Options:");

    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Media Explorer",@"Live TV",@"Settings",nil];
    itemImges = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"listicon_guide.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"listicon_livetv.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"listicon_settings.png"],
             nil];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];

    MediaExpDetailViewController *DVCA = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MediaExpDetailViewController"];
    LiveTVDetailViewController *DVCB = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LiveTVDetailViewController"];
    SettingsDetailViewController *DVCC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingsDetailViewController"];

    //Create Array of views
    viewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:DVCA, DVCB, DVCC, nil];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *object = items[indexPath.row];
    UIImage *image = itemImges[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    cell.imageView.image = image;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //for iPad
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        //something goes here
    }
    else { //for iPhone
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        MediaExpDetailViewController *objSynergy = (MediaExpDetailViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MediaExpDetailViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objSynergy animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
}

@end
```

Comment: push (into the nav controller) instead of present

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First set Storyboard IDs for your Next View controllers in Interface Builder and then.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // Check Row and Select Next View controller
   if (indexPath.row == 1)
   {     
       // Push Selected View
       UIViewController *view1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryboardID"];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:view1 animated:YES];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because

```
[self presentViewController:obj animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Presents the new view controller modally (over top of the existing visible controller). If you want to push to a new view controller using your navigation controller, you'll want to use this. Of course you'll want to make sure that the view controller you're pushing from is embedded within a UINavigationController.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

And to answer your first question, yes it absolutely is possible. Just add some condition logic to your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (someCondition) {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
    }else{
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:otherObj animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do [self.navigationController pushViewController:otherObj animated:YES]; i get error message in log: 2013-11-22 14:23:53.849 iAmuse[1651:c07] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2013-11-22 14:23:54.203 iAmuse[1651:c07] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2013-11-22 14:23:54.204 iAmuse[1651:c07] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <MediaExpDetailViewController: 0x7587da0>.

Comment: @lugonja How many times are you calling `pushViewController:` in your function?

Comment: Only once in my case statement. Maybe I am missing something here. Also when I click on item I am not getting my obj view controller, but  default view controller from template of master/detail app.

Comment: @lugonja How are you accessing it? And is it possible that you added the call to pushViweController, and left the call to presentViewController intact?

Answer (score 0):

Modally presented view controllers don't have navigation bars by default. You have to embed them in a UINavigationController, in order to have one. You should also implement how to dismiss the presented view controller by yourself, calling **dismissViewControllerAnimated** at the appropriate times.

However, I'd recommend to *push* your view controllers (with **pushViewControllerAnimated**), instead of presenting them modally, if you don't specifically need the modal functionality.